# Pandas: join DataFrames on field with different names?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, field

According to [this documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html#left-outer-join) I can only make a join between fields having the same name.

Do you know if it's possible to join two DataFrames on a field having different names?

The equivalent in SQL would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM df1
LEFT OUTER JOIN df2
  ON df1.id_key = df2.fk_key
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I think what you want is possible using `merge`. Pass in the keyword arguments for `left_on` and `right_on` to tell Pandas which column(s) from each DataFrame to use as keys:

```
pandas.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['id_key'], right_on=['fk_key'])
```

The documentation describes this in more detail on [this page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Answer (score -7):

df2['id_key'] = df2['fk_key'].str.lower()

df1['id_key'] = df1['id_key'].str.lower()

## Now try to merge the  dataframes

df3 = pd.merge(df2,df1,how='inner', on='id_key')

Comment: This doesn't answer this question